# bluebird Promise chain this reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

i am struggling with a class with several functions. Each of them returns a promise.

My problem is, that after the first return of a Promise, the this-reference in the next function is not the class object but the global node object.

Here is some sample code:

index.js:

```
"use strict";

const debug = require("./dbg.js");
const testClass = require("./testClass.js");


const dbg = new debug();

const tc = new testClass(dbg);


tc.printTestMessage()
    .then(tc.Test1)
    .then(tc.Test2)
    .then(tc.Test3);
```

testClass.js:

```
"use strict";


const Promise = require("bluebird");

let testClass = function(dbg) {

let self = this;

self._dbg = dbg;



};

testClass.prototype.printTestMessage = function() {

    let self = this;

    return new Promise(function(resolve) {

        self._dbg.printDebug(3, "testClass - printTestMessage", "start printing...");

        setTimeout(function() {

            self._dbg.printDebug(3, "testClass - printTestMessage", "finished printing...");
        resolve();

        }, 2000);

    });

};


testClass.prototype.Test1 = function() {

    let self = this;

    return new Promise(function(resolve) {

        self._dbg.printDebug(3, "testClass - Test1", "start printing...");

        setTimeout(function() {

            self._dbg.printDebug(3, "testClass - Test1", "finished printing...");
            resolve();

        }, 2000);

    });

};


testClass.prototype.Test2 = function() {

    let self = this;

    return new Promise(function(resolve) {

        self._dbg.printDebug(3, "testClass - Test2", "start printing...");

       setTimeout(function() {

            self._dbg.printDebug(3, "testClass - Test2", "finished printing...");
            resolve();

        }, 2000);

    });

};


testClass.prototype.Test3 = function() {

    let self = this;

    return new Promise(function(resolve) {

        self._dbg.printDebug(3, "testClass - Test3", "start printing...");

        setTimeout(function() {

            self._dbg.printDebug(3, "testClass - Test3", "finished printing...");
            resolve();

        }, 2000);

    });

};




module.exports = testClass;
```

Any help on how to stick in each function to the class reference?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found it on my own: Each new Promise has to add .bind(self) at the end.

eg:

```
testClass.prototype.Test3 = function() {

    let self = this;

    return new Promise(function(resolve) {

        self._dbg.printDebug(3, "testClass - Test3", "start printing...");

        setTimeout(function() {

            self._dbg.printDebug(3, "testClass - Test3", "finished printing...");
            resolve();

        }, 2000);

    }).bind(self); //<-- this is the important part

};
```

Comment: afaik, Promises have no `bind` method, and using `.bind(this)` inside a function called with the wrong `this` object, won't fix your error. You'd have to use the `bind` here `.then(tc.Test3.bind(tc))`

Comment: @Thomas - The question is tagged with "Bluebird" and [Bluebird promises](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/bind.html) do have a `.bind()` method.

Comment: @Thomas you are wrong, bluebird has a bind method. So why negative vote?

Comment: I didn't vote. I had an opinion, jfriend corrected me; I'm fine